# How can I send XML from my Python script to my web page using Ajax?

Tags: python, ajax, xml, apache, raspberry-pi

I'm running an Apache server on my Raspberry Pi 2, hosting a simple index.htm at my ip address (located at /var/www).  I've created a python file that is saved at /usr/lib/cgi-bin.  I've setup all the appropriate permissions and have had success running Python scripts from the directory.

My goal is to run a python script that will send XML to my webpage at index.htm, and then have my index.htm display this data on the webpage.  I've tried using Ajax to get this done, but I've had no luck.  (I'm new to Python, so if this isn't possible with Python, let me know).

Below is what I've tried...my index page has a **p** tag which says "what's up", and then when I get the XML response, I want it to change to "hanging out".  That's it.

To clarify, this is how I imagine this would work:

**index.htm sends POST request to xmlTest.py >> xmlTest.py responds and sends back XML to index.htm >> index.htm reads the XML response and changes value on page**

Here's what I've tried:

index.htm

```
 <html>

<head>
<title>
Pi Test
</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function sendAjax(){
     var nocache = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            if (this.responseXML != null) {

        document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('data')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}}}


    request3.open("POST", "/cgi-bin/xmlTest.py", true);
    request3.send();
}



</script>



</head>

<body onload="sendAjax()">

<center>hello</center>
<p id="paragraph">What's up?</p>

</body>

</html>
```

And this is my xmlTest.py file located at /usr/lib/cgi-bin:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import httplibimport re

from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
target_url = "/index.htm"
xml_request = """\    
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  <inputs>
     <data>hanging out</data>
  </inputs>    
"""  


def send_xml():
  ''' sends xml request to url with parameter request '''
  result = urllib.urlopen( target_url, urllib.urlencode( {'request':xml_request} ) )
  #parse results and print the xml or do whatever with it
  print parse( result ).toprettyxml()
  return result
  result.close()

def main():  
  send_xml()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

When I visit ipaddress/cgi-bin/xmlTest.py , I get "Internal Server Error".  I believe the line causing that was: import httplibimport re

So I removed it, but now when I refresh, I get the following error:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: open_file() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) 
      args = ('open_file() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)',) 
      message = 'open_file() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)'
```

Comment: Your description seems to have missed out the bit where you make a request to a PHP server. Why are you doing that? And you'll need to give some more information about where it is going wrong. Is that request being made? Are you seeing the results of the `print`?

Comment: Oh, that was a mistake.  I changed it to index.htm  Added an edit that hopefully helps narrow down what's going wrong..

Comment: But now that makes even less sense. The static HTML file makes an Ajax request to the CGI script, which in turn makes a request back to the HTML file? Why?

Comment: Yea, I don't want to make another request.  I think what I want to do is send an XML response (as seen in the ajax function on the html page).  Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, you can send anything you like. Whatever you print in a CGI script is sent back to the client. But you need to print proper HTTP headers too, plus a blank line between the headers and the content.

Comment: have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32182/simple-command-line-http-server